# I am trying to do object detection using Yolov5 and modify the model. How can I do that?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, object-detection, yolo

I want to modify Yolov5 and see how it performs. Here's the yaml file https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/models/yolov5s.yaml

How do the make the changes in the yaml file if I want to introduce some transformers or some other layers of CBAM and so on. I saw some papers were changing the model. But how do I just do it? I have no idea.
Can someone please give me some tips and suggestions.
Thanks!